# How to use WiX preprocessor pragmas?

Tags: wix, preprocessor, wix-extension

I'm currently working on a test WiX project to see what I can do with it.

Recently, I've stumbled upon the fact that I can override the `ProcessPragma` method in my preprocessor extension to write WiX source code at compile time. Having a preprocessor function that returns an xml string without the compiler going berserk sounds neat. So I looked into it, but the response in [this wix-users thread](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27552185) is quite brief and doesn't explain much. Google doesn't return anything interesting beyond that. So I dug through the WiX source code to learn more.

The xml documentation for the method is as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Processes a pragma defined in the extension.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sourceLineNumbers">The location of this pragma's PI.</param>
/// <param name="prefix">The prefix of the pragma to be processed by the extension.</param>
/// <param name="pragma">The name of the pragma.</param>
/// <param name="args">The pragma's arguments.</param>
/// <param name="writer">The xml writer.</param>
/// <returns>false if the pragma is not defined.</returns>
/// <comments>Don't return false for any condition except for unrecognized pragmas. 
    Throw errors that are fatal to the compile. use core.OnMessage for warnings and messages.</comments>
```

So as a test, I had the `XmlWriter` produce a dummy property and then return true.

Now, to actually call it in my WiX project. In `Preprocessor.cs`, I found the following:

```
switch (reader.NodeType)
{
    case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
        switch (reader.LocalName)
        {
            // other cases such as define, include, foreach, 
            // and other preprocessor directives                
            case "pragma":
                this.PreprocessPragma(reader.Value, writer);
                break;
        }
        break;
```

Which hinted that the syntax for using a pragma would be: `<?pragma prefix.name?>`

But this gives me the following warning: `The pragma 'prefix.name' is unknown. Please ensure you have referenced the extension that defines this pragma.`

I have a feeling I'm on the right track, as it gives me a warning related to pragmas, but I honestly have no clue what I'm doing here. It seems like it's uncharted territory.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

Seems like my project was the problem. I used my extension in another project and it worked like a charm.

And for anyone reading this in the future, the syntax is `<?pragma prefix.name args?>` where the arguments are just a string. And as a side note, you don't close the `XmlWriter` in your override method.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure you are passing the `-ext path\to\YourPragmaExtensionAssembly.dll` to `candle.exe`. Candle will load your extension, look for the `AssemblyDefaultWixExtension` attribute that points to the class that inherits from WixExtension, then ask for your `PreprocessorExtension` class if you override the `PreprocessorExtension` property.

It's a little bit of wiring up that could be simplified in future versions (like v4.0) of the WiX toolset. But there is an example in the WiX v3.x toolset at: `src\ext\PreProcExampleExtension\wixext` that should show the way.

Comment: It seems the problem was in my project and not the extension itself. I tried using it in another project and it worked fine.